# Why is there no F statistic and p value for this one way anova?

Tags: r, anova

My data is the mean per group as shown below

```
Group    Mean Value
A        215.3205
B        253.3994
C        214.1516
D        271.1881
E        209.4847
```

I did a one way anova

```
summary (aov(df$Mean Value ~ df$Group))
```

and my results are

```
       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
 df$Group   4  3095   773.7
```

Why is there no FStatistic and p value?

Comment: You only have one data point per group, the within variance is therefore zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the pre-computed group mean values instead of the individual records that were used to compute the mean values. To calculate an ANOVA, you need to know the number of observations, sum of squares, etc. Not just the mean values. `aov` will calculate all these things for you as long as you pass the individual records.

Here is an example using the `PlantGrowth` data:

`summary(aov(weight~group, PlantGrowth))`